# I wish to merge categories from a factor variable to reduce the number of levels

Tags: r, if-statement

I have this dataset bank-full with a variable job summary(bank.full$job)

```
       admin.   blue-collar  entrepreneur     housemaid    management 
         5171          9732          1487          1240          9458 
      retired self-employed      services       student    technician 
         2264          1579          4154           938          7597 
   unemployed       unknown 
         1303           288
```

This is the percent cross tab of the variable with the target variable y

```
                no  yes
  admin.        0.88 0.12
  blue-collar   0.93 0.07
  entrepreneur  0.92 0.08
  housemaid     0.92 0.08
  management    0.87 0.13
  retired       0.83 0.17
  self-employed 0.89 0.11
  services      0.91 0.09
  student       0.72 0.28
  technician    0.90 0.10
  unemployed    0.84 0.16
  unknown       0.89 0.11
```

Now I wish to merge job categories whose cross tab values are similar
I used this two approaches

```
 bank.full$newjob<-ifelse(c(bank.full$job=='admin.',
                            bank.full$job=='self-employed',
                            bank.full$job=='unknown'),'CAT1',
                   ifelse(c(bank.full$job=='blue-collar',
                            bank.full$job=='entrepreneur'),'CAT2',
                   ifelse(c(bank.full$job=='housemaid',
                            bank.full$job=='services'),'CAT3',
                   ifelse(c(bank.full$job=='management',
                            bank.full$job=='unemployed',
                            bank.full$job=='technician'),'CAT4',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='student','student','retired')))))
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, newjob, value = c("CAT4", "retired",  : 
  replacement has 135633 rows, data has 45211
```

Second Approach

```
bank.full$newjob<-ifelse(bank.full$job=='admin.','CAT1',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='self-employed','CAT1',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='unknown'),'CAT1',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='blue-collar','CAT2',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='entrepreneur','CAT2',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='housemaid','CAT3',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='services','CAT3',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='management','CAT4',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='unemployed','CAT4',
                   ifelse(bank.full$job=='technician','CAT4',"")))))))))
Error in ifelse(bank.full$job == "self-employed", "CAT1", ifelse(bank.full$job ==  : 
  unused arguments ("CAT1", ifelse(bank.full$job == "blue-collar", "CAT2", ifelse(bank.full$job == 
"entrepreneur", "CAT2", ifelse(bank.full$job == "housemaid", "CAT3", ifelse(bank.full$job == "services", "CAT3", ifelse(bank.full$job == "management", "CAT4", ifelse(bank.full$job == "unemployed", "CAT4",
 ifelse(bank.full$job == "technician", "CAT4", ""))))))))
```

I was able to get an output till this level but when i inserted all the if conditions it's giving me a an error

```
bank.full$newjob<-ifelse(bank.full$job=='admin.','CAT1',
+                          ifelse(bank.full$job=='self-employed','CAT1',
+                                 ifelse(bank.full$job=='unknown','CAT1',
+ ifelse(c(bank.full$job=='blue-collar',bank.full$job=='entrepreneur'),'CAT2',""))))
> bank.full$newjob<-as.factor(bank.full$newjob)
> summary(bank.full$newjob)
> summary(bank.full$newjob)
       CAT1  CAT2 
28441  7038  9732
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this approach:

```
bank.full$newjob<- 'CAT0'
bank.full$newjob<- ifelse(test= bank.full$job %in% c('admin.','self-employed','unknown'), yes='CAT1',no=bank.full$job)
bank.full$newjob<- ifelse(test= bank.full$job %in% c('blue-collar','entrepreneur'), yes='CAT2',no=bank.full$job)
bank.full$newjob<- ifelse(test= bank.full$job %in% c('management','unemployed','technician'), yes='CAT3',no=bank.full$job)
```

this approach will work. I would do something else - merging factor levels (search it out)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer @Zahiro Mor
The approach that you mentioned didn't quite work as I was getting only CAT4 level and the same previous levels.But I tried the combineLevels function that you mentioned and it was working perfectly

```
install.packages("rockchalk");library(rockchalk)
levels(bank.full$month)
bank.full$job<-combineLevels(bank.full$job,levs =c('admin.','self-employed','unknown'),newLabel = 'CAT1' )
bank.full$job<-combineLevels(bank.full$job,levs =c('blue-collar','entrepreneur'),newLabel = 'CAT2' )
bank.full$job<-combineLevels(bank.full$job,levs =c('housemaid','services'),newLabel = 'CAT3' )
bank.full$job<-combineLevels(bank.full$job,levs =c('management','unemployed','technician'),newLabel = 'CAT4' )
bank.full$job<-combineLevels(bank.full$job,levs =c('student','retired'),newLabel = 'CAT5' )
```

This is the output that I got after running the final line

```
The original levels retired student CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 CAT4 
have been replaced by CAT1 CAT2 CAT3 CAT4 CAT5
```

So far the easiest method that I came across to replace the functions